# How can I add a string to my LINQ query using C#?

Tags: linq

I want concatenate a string in LINQ my query is:

```
var OnePoste =
    from cr in bd.Staxe
    where cr.Date_Comm >= dateTime1 && cr.Date_Comm <= dateTime2
    select cr.Id;
```

```
mystring = " && (coutCommInt1 == 0 || cr.Mt_Comm_C >= coutCommInt1)
             && (coutCommInt2 == 0 || cr.Mt_Comm_C <= coutCommInt2)"
```

How can I add `mystring`  in my query LINQ ?

Comment: Add where in the query?

Comment: I tried to add clarity with some minor grammar and formatting updates but frankly it still does not appear to have enough clarity to enable us to properly answer.  Perhaps you can modify it to help us understand your intent/goal here?

Comment: 'HI,'
'i want write like'
```
var OnePoste =
    from cr in bd.Staxe
    where cr.Date_Comm >= dateTime1 && cr.Date_Comm <= dateTime2 + mystring 
    select cr.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

'HI,'
'i want write like'

```
var OnePoste =
    from cr in bd.Staxe
    where cr.Date_Comm >= dateTime1 && cr.Date_Comm <= dateTime2 + mystring 
    select cr.Id;
```

Comment: Update original question and remove this non-answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).